# Alternative way to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)=\mathbb{Q}(a + b)$ for certain $a, b$

Tags: group-theory, extension-field

I want to know if there is an alternative method to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)=\mathbb{Q}(a + b)$ (I know this doesn't happen for any $a, b$). For example, to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3})$ I would write the explicit expression of any element in each body, and then realize that they are the same.
This is easy to do here because $(\sqrt{2})^2\in \mathbb{Q}$ (the same for $\sqrt{3}$). However, if I have roots of a higher degree $n$ this process is very long. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Are you ok to find and factorize $MinPoly_Q(a)$ and $MinPoly_{Q(a)}(b)$ in an extension $F$ where they split completely ? If so $Q(a,b)=Q(a+b)$ iff for each $\sigma\in Hom(Q(a,b),F)$ we have ' $\sigma(a+b)=a+b$ iff $\sigma(a)=a,\sigma(b)=b$'